# MYSQL why would min be larger than max?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

```
select min(lead), max(lead)
from products 
WHERE part_line != 90 and category = 'x'
```

When I run the above query the min returned is larger than the max. If I remove the condition pline != 90 the problem goes away.

I was thinking at first that mysql was processing the min, max before it got to pline... but that doesn't explain why it would assign a higher min.

What gets me, when I get the avg() it calculates correctly.

What's going on?

Comment: Got example data?  Sounds like you're running MIN/MAX on column that use a text/string data type...

Comment: I second that, min/max works on many different data types, and they have other meanings, check the data type, or tell us what data type u used :)

Comment: Didn't even think to check, my lead field was set to varchar for some reason... I changed to int and problem solved. Was pulling my hair our, never experienced that issue before.  OMG Ponies, post a answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you could have written an answer, since you're right... The correct SQL syntax is: select min(cast(lead as signed)),max(cast(lead as signed)) from products where part_line!=90 and category='x';

Comment: If only there were a [promote comment to answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49563/promoting-comments-to-answers) feature ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe your fields are treated as text so, for example 21 will be smallest than 3 (alphabetical order)
If that fields are type of TEXT try to cast values to INT()

Comment: Field was datatype varchar, converted to integer and problem solved! 

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sql server example:

```
with Test_CTE (first, second, third)
as(
    select '21 ', 'b', 1
    union
    select '3  ', 'd', 2
)
select MIN(first) as Minimum, MAX(first) as Maximum 
from Test_CTE
```

output is

```
Minimum Maximum
21      3
```

Note that the values are Text data with trailing spaces, hence the reason it's sorted differently from how you *might* expect.